# KIWI TCMS behaves strangely during cloning Test Case

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have a problem with the function of Clone Test Case, which behaves differently than specified in the manual.

In Test Case, I click on CLONE to open the Filter plan form, and when I click Filter Plan, I get the results table (see. picture).
I miss any button to go back with a confirmed Test plan selection.

If I click to back button of browser, Kiwi TCMS falls and I have to start over again. Please do you have some solution of this, because in manual is different specification.

I expect the test plan selection option.

The Test plan selection is not displayed correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swI9v.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/695/ which has already been fixed.

Try reproducing on https://demo.kiwitcms.org and report back if it happens, otherwise upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: ok. In your demo (v. 6.5.3) is this bug fixed. And we use version 6.3. Wi will update it. Thanks for help us.